# How to integrate Kafka and Flink in Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I am trying to develop a test Flink application that reads from and writes to a Kafka topic.

However, I have been getting this error:

```
start writing data to kafka
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 71, in <module>
    write_to_kafka(env)
  File "teste.py", line 45, in write_to_kafka
    env.execute()
  File "/Users/lauracorssac/miniconda3/envs/pyflink_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/stream_execution_environment.py", line 764, in execute
    return JobExecutionResult(self._j_stream_execution_environment.execute(j_stream_graph))
  File "/Users/lauracorssac/miniconda3/envs/pyflink_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/lauracorssac/miniconda3/envs/pyflink_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/lauracorssac/miniconda3/envs/pyflink_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1277)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:240)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:715)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RuntimeContext.getMetricGroup()Lorg/apache/flink/metrics/MetricGroup;
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initProducer(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:1365)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initNonTransactionalProducer(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:1342)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.beginTransaction(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:990)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.beginTransaction(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.beginTransactionInternal(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:436)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.initializeState(TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java:427)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initializeState(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:1195)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:171)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.initializeOperatorState(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:122)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:283)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:726)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:702)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:904)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My code:

```py
# Make sure that the Kafka cluster is started and the topic 'test_json_topic' is
# created before executing this job.
def write_to_kafka(env):
    type_info = Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])
    ds = env.from_collection(
        [(1, 'hi'), (2, 'hello'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hello'), (5, 'hi'), (6, 'hello'), (6, 'hello')],
        type_info=type_info)

    serialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.Builder() \
        .with_type_info(type_info) \
        .build()
    kafka_producer = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        topic='test_json_topic',
        serialization_schema=serialization_schema,
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group'}
    )
    # note that the output type of ds must be RowTypeInfo
    ds.add_sink(kafka_producer)
    env.execute()


def read_from_kafka(env):
    deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.Builder() \
        .type_info(Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])) \
        .build()
    kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test_json_topic',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group_1'}
    )
    kafka_consumer.set_start_from_earliest()
    env.add_source(kafka_consumer).print()
    env.execute('oi')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format="%(message)s")

    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars("file:///Users/lauracorssac/HiWiProj/flink-connector-base-1.16.0.jar")
    env.add_jars("file:///Users/lauracorssac/HiWiProj/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar")

    print("start writing data to kafka")
    write_to_kafka(env)

    print("start reading data from kafka")
    read_from_kafka(env)
```

As the code shows, I tried to download many and different jars from the Maven repository. Nothing worked.

Comment: You need to use a consistent Flink version for your JARs. What version of Flink did you install? Use that for your JARs... Also, `connect-file` is not what you want.

Comment: 1.16 is the version. I tried to add the same connectors only in theirs 1.16 version but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to use `1.16` JAR versions of `flink-connector-base` and `flink-sql-connector-kafka` and any new errors you get when doing so, and remove `connect-file`

Comment: Did so! The errors did not change so much though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that only by explicitly adding flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar by:

```
env.add_jars("file:///Users/lauracorssac/HiWiProj/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar")
```

was not enough. I had also to delete the version of the jar that comes with pyflink located at: `/path/to/python/site-packages/pyflink/lib/`.

In my case it was :

```
.../miniconda3/envs/pyflink_38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.13.0.jar
```

Also, do not forget to set Java version to 1.8. I was having this issue as well. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: I suspect Java 11 should work as well. But it "came with 1.13" even though you're using 1.16? Again, you'll need to use consistent versions, so upgrade Flink altogether rather than use different connector versions